# Conditional Formatting xlwt

Tags: python, formatting, conditional-statements, xlrd, xlwt

I have seen some posts that say you can NOT perform conditional formatting using `xlwt`, but they were rather old. I was curious if this has evolved?

I have been searching for about half a day now. Furthermore, if I con't write it directly from `xlwt`, can I create an `.xls` file containing a single cell with the conditional format I want and have `xlrd` read that format and paste it into the sheet I aim to produce then using `xlwt`?

Comment: I am not sure if the above is completely true..See this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448882/conditionally-formatting-text-strings-from-excel-using-python

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`xlrd` and `xlwt` still *don't support conditional formatting*. `xlrd` doesn't read it, `xlwt` doesn't write it.

There is a new and awesome module, called [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/). *It does support [conditional formatting](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html) out of the box*. The project is active, documentation is pretty good. Plus, there are a lot of [examples](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html).

Here's an example:

```
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

workbook = Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write('A1', 49)
worksheet.write('A2', 51)

format1 = workbook.add_format({'bold': 1, 'italic': 1})
worksheet.conditional_format('A1:A2', {'type': 'cell',
                                       'criteria': '>=',
                                       'value': 50,
                                       'format': format1})
workbook.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

True that xlswriter makes formatting pretty easy, but i think it can not be used for appending data tpsheets, which i feel is a big drawback.