# xlwt/xlutils.copy doesn't preserve cell (which I didn't touch) format

Tags: python, excel, xlwt, xlutils

I am writing a python script to add a new sheet in a `xls` file, and I am using `xlrd`, `xlutils.copy` and `xlwt` to do it. Here is what my code looks like :

```
wb=xlwt.Workbook()
rb=xlrd.open_workbook(MY_FILE_PATH, formatting_info=True)           
wb = copy(rb)   
sht1 = wb.add_sheet('newSheet')
-- add some data
wb.save(MY_FILE_PATH)
```

The thing is, the formats for some cells which I didn't touch in the existing sheets (you can see I only add a new sheet) get changed. To be specific, I have two changes:

- Some cells which originally have format as date (which by default
  have format as `yyyy/m/d`)now have format as customized (and format
  string as `m/d/yy`).
- I lose all foramts I set in the `conditional formatting`.

Could someone tell me how can I preserve the format in the cells that I don't need to modify?  I am using `python 3.5.5 64 bits` on `windows` and `xlrd version 1.1.0`, `xlutils 2.0.0`, `xlwt 1.3.0` . Thank you very much!

update:

I did more test by changing the last call `wb.save(MY_FILE_PATH)` to `wb.save(MY_FILE_PATH_2)`, i.e., I saved the file by a new name. I can see that only after the `save` call the file get changed (the original MY_FILE_PATH remained the same in this case). And actually the size of the newly-saved file was smaller than the original one, even though the new file had a sheet added. This suggests that in the `save` call some formatting information was lost. At least from what I can see the `conditional formatting` was lost which reduced the size (I assume the change of date format doesn't affect the file size too much).

Comment: did you try opening it with excel and libre office calc to see if it is coming from excel or it is your code

Comment: @KostadinSlavov in which step you mean? When I opened the file before the `open_workbook` call the file was untouched and as desired. And next call `copy` made an individual copy of the original file in the memory and all operations after thant until the last line `save` were made to this copy, not to original file directly (in another word this file was not changed when I opened it in Excel and checked), and only after the `save` call, the changes I described were added and saved to the file in the disk.

Comment: It sounds like the modules you're using are reading in the entire sheet but missing the conditional formatting. That would explain my they are not correctly writing them back out again. Have you considered trying xlsxwriter instead? See https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/

Comment: @DavidGaertner Does it also work with `xls` format? Because I need to deal with legacy spreadsheets in old format. When I searched online I see that `openpyxl` only works with `xlsx`, and to my understanding from your link so does `xlsxwriter`?

Comment: The xls format is an interesting twist. I wonder if reading using xlrd and writing use xlsxwriter is an option. Also, I found this answer, and I hope it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448882/conditionally-formatting-text-strings-from-excel-using-python

Comment: @DavidGaertner In the comment section of the market answer on your link it says that the `conditional formatting` is lost. And @Murli in mentioned in his answer (and some people mentioned in some other questions) that it is because `xlrd` doesn't read the `conditional formatting` info. So I guess importing from `xlrd` and wirting using `openpyxl` (or `xlsxwriter`) won't work either. I guess I'd be better off using other language / library such as C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like xlrd doesn't support conditional formatting yet.

You can check out the error logs by passing verbosity=1 to open_workbook function.

> rb=xlrd.open_workbook(MY_FILE_PATH, formatting_info=True, verbosity=1)

Alternatively, [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formatting.html) seems to have support for *"Conditional Formatting"*. Can check this package instead.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the way to check the error log. Now I see the log contains may entries of `*** WARNING: Ignoring CONDFMT (conditional formatting) record`. And since `openpyxl` doesn't seem to work with `xls` files, I guess I have to give up python and try to find other tools to do the job