# conditional formatting using xlwt python

Tags: python, excel

Is there a way to do conditional formatting using xlwt? Because mostly of my code already using xlwt.

like this. some of the code

```
import xlwt

....

for filename in glob.glob(openSoundingFile):
    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="latin1")

    sheet = wb.add_sheet('INPUT')
    sheet2 = wb.add_sheet('TRANSFER')

    newName = filename
    spamReader = csv.reader(open(filename, 'rb'), delimiter=';',quotechar='"')
    for rowx, row in enumerate(spamReader):
        for colx, value in enumerate(row):
            sheet.write(rowx, colx, value)   

    sheet.col(0).width = 5555
    sheet.col(1).width = 11110
    sheet.col(2).width = 5555
    sheet.col(3).width = 3333
....
```

and i want to input this code. but this thing is not working because it need xlsxwriter

```
sheet2.conditional_format('G28:G528:', {'type': 'cell','criteria': '>','value': 100,'format': yellow})
```

if more than 100 the cell color become yellow. Thanks for any reply

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional Formatting xlwt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176738/conditional-formatting-xlwt)